# Android Twofish File Encryption Tutorials?

Tags: twofish

I'm making an app for android to encrypt files. I want to use TwoFish as my algorithm but I don't know how to do encryption. Can someone direct me to a basic tutorial site or better covering how to use the TwoFish?

Answer (score 0):

With about 5 seconds invested in a [google search](http://www.example-code.com/android/crypt2_twofish.asp). I am very confident that there is a better solution than reinventing/copying the wheel so you might re-evaluate if you simply use this code or look for an alternative. For instance [javax.crypto](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) could probably do what you seek to achieve in a more future-oriented way.